# Generic BitConverter-like method?

Tags: c#, marshalling, unsafe

I've recently encountered a situation where I need to create a generic method to read a datatype out of a byte array.

I've created the following class:

```
public class DataStream
{
    public int Offset { get; set; }

    public byte[] Data { get; set; }

    public T Read<T>() where T : struct
    {
        unsafe
        {
            int dataLen = Marshal.SizeOf( typeof( T ) );
            IntPtr dataBlock = Marshal.AllocHGlobal( dataLen );


            Marshal.Copy( Data, Offset, dataBlock, dataLen );


            T type = *( ( T* )dataBlock.ToPointer() );

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal( dataBlock );

            Offset += dataLen;

            return type;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, de-allocation issues aside, this code doesn't compile with this message:

```
Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('T')
```

Which, seems strange because you should be able to do the above operations based on the `where T : struct` constraint on the method.

If this code is horribly incorrect, is there any simple way to take a series of bytes and cast them into a '`T`' type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of trying to do this via pointer manipulation, you should switch your code to use [Mashal.PtrToStructure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx).  This method is specifically designed for this scenario.

Answer (score 8):

Since answer has already been given, let me just explain why your original code didn't work for you:

> Which, seems strange because you should be able to do the above operations based on the where T : struct constraint on the method.

Not really. You can have raw pointers to *unmanaged types*. This is defined as follows in the C# language spec (18.2):

> Unlike references (values of reference types), pointers are not tracked by the garbage collector — the garbage collector has no knowledge of pointers and the data to which they point. For this reason a pointer is not permitted to point to a reference or to a struct that contains references, and the referent type of a pointer must be an *unmanaged-type*.
>   An *unmanaged-type* is any type that isn’t a reference-type and doesn’t contain reference-type fields at any level of nesting. In other words, an *unmanaged-type* is one of the following:
>
> - `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `char`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`, or `bool`.
> - Any *enum-type*.
> - Any *pointer-type*.
> - Any user-defined *struct-type* that contains fields of *unmanaged-types* only.

So there are quite a few restrictions, and for a generic method, `T:struct` may or may not conform to them for any particular instantiation, so construct like `T*` is illegal. It would be nice to have a special generic type parameter constraint to cover unmanaged types, but as it stands, there isn't one in the CLR.

Comment: Ah I see. I never considered that a struct constraint could potentially allow other sorts of managed types into the mix.

Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

At one point I wrote [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ReadingStructuresEmit.aspx) explaining how to do exactly that, but many times faster than the Marshal.PtrToStructure.  The code sample uses dynamic code generation to copy the generic type T to/from bit stream.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming:

- A Sequential or Explicit Structure (otherwise very bad idea)
- Correct data sizes (you should pre-check & throw)

---

```
unsafe TStruct BytesToStructure<TStruct>(byte[] data) where TStruct : struct
{
    fixed (byte* dataPtr = data)
        return (TStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(dataPtr), typeof(TStruct));
}

unsafe byte[] StructureToBytes<TStruct>(TStruct st) where TStruct : struct
{
    var bytes = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(st)];
    fixed (byte* ptr = bytes) Marshal.StructureToPtr(st, new IntPtr(ptr), true);
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: This are the best and the most compact solutions I have ever seen. I started to use them and they are really useful.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this a while back to do the same thing: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33713/Generic-BinaryReader-and-BinaryWriter-Extensions

You'll have to add a C++/CLI project to your Visual Studio solution though.